# Xamarin 5 UWP - Issue with DisplayAlert

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

Me and my team have just migrated our cross-platform XF 4 project to XF5.

The only issue that we have encountered thus far is the following:
Our UWP App was throwing an unhandled App.Xaml exception when navigating to a different page for no apparent reason and after some search, installing the nugget **Microsoft.UI.Xaml** explicitly fixed that issue, even though that nugget package is supposed to be installed along with XF5 nugget.

But right now a new issue has emerged. When calling the `await Application.Current.MainPage.**DisplayAlert**(szTitle, szMessage, btnOk, btnCancel);` from the UI thread the alert gets displayed properly but when I click on one of its buttons Ι get an unhandled exception

`"No installed components were detected. The property path '(controls:AnimatedIcon.State)' could not be resolved for a Setter." where controls is defined as xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"`

Could you please help me find out what is going wrong?
As far as I know the `DisplayAlert()` is handled by `Xamarin.Forms`.

Comment: After add the WinUI nugget package, and have you specific  `XamlControlsResources` for uwp app like this [`<XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thank you for your quick reply!
After installing the Microsoft.UI.Xaml  nugget my App.xaml is as followed:
<Application
    x:Class="gr.entersoft.universal.uwp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
But I still get the same runtime unhandled exception as mentioned in the description. Do you think I'm missing something?

Comment: Yep, I tried make a code sample with your description,  but I can't reproduce your problem, any simple sample could be share?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I'm sorry for my late reply.
Here is the link to the sample project on my GitHub that reproduces the issue:
https://github.com/Koub96/Xamarin-5
Please let me know if you find out what is going wrong, we are trying to figure it out for a long time. And thank you for your help!

Comment: I could repro the problem with above your code sample, but it looks share project? why not  use the  .netstandard project?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Unfortunately, the structure of the project cannot change because there are 2 more UWP projects that share code through the shared UWP library. And the same logic is followed by the Android and iOS projects that I didn't include. What do you think that produces the issue?

Comment: It's hard to say, for this problem, we suggest you post a new bug report in WInUI github issue box [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thank you, I will open a new issue . Please let me know in case something comes up.

Comment: Yep, I will update below if have any information.

Comment: And I found  the dependency lib of sf package contains WInUI. it may not compatible with WinUI library, please make blank sample that only contains WInUI library.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Could you please elaborate a bit more? Do you think that a certain nugget that has dependency to the same WinUI library ( Microsoft.UI.Xaml ) causes the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure, but  a certain nugget that has dependency to the same WinUI library. You could make a new sample and only add WinUI library for testing.